# Docker multi-stage building fork instead of chain

Tags: node.js, docker

I would like to use multi-stage building for a dev and prod images. I am currently in a node environment.

I want the dev images to contain all the dependencies (dev and prod) and no source code (I intend to mount the source code) whereas the production image would contain only the production dependencies and the source code will be copied inside it.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.12.0 AS base

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY package*.json ./


FROM base AS development

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "debug"]


FROM base AS production

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The issue I am facing is that when I build the production image, the process go through the whole Dockerfile. I would like to make some kind of fork:

node -> base -> dev or node -> base -> prod
instead of
node -> base -> dev or node -> base -> dev -> prod

Is that possible ?

If not, is my issue a real issue or am I trying to achieve a useless goal because the production image overwrite the specificities of the dev image and so I should not care about going through the whole process ?

Comment: is that what do you want `docker build --target production -t test-counter:latest ` ?

Comment: By doing that, I go through the full process building a dev image. I am afraid, it will cause conflict between dev and prof images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not, is my issue a real issue or am I trying to achieve a useless goal because the production image overwrite the specificities of the dev image and so I should not care about going through the whole process ?

Multi-stage images create multiple images, and then tag the one you request. In this case, nothing in the prod image depends on the dev image so they are created independently of each other. Nothing is overwritten in dev by prod, and nothing changed in dev is in the prod image.

The only impact is slower builds since you run the `npm install` twice, but only if the `package*.json` has changed since the last build. If you want to further speed up the build, consider switching to BuildKit which creates a dependency graph of your Dockerfile and runs only the needed stages to create your target stage. Enabling that is done with an environment variable on 18.09 or newer versions of docker:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build --target=production image_name:prod .
```

If you want to make that the new default, there's a feature flag that can be set in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`